# OWASP ZAP not showing requests to images in history view

Tags: owasp, zap

I'm investigating some strange behavior in a web application where something is generating requests that shouldn't be there. Since the principal action triggering these requests opens a new browser window, browser built-in network debugging capabilities do not help. I'd like, for now, to just view the raw requests going over the wire. So, I've installed [OWASP ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) to use it as a local proxy.

To my surprise, it looks like OWASP ZAP does not show any requests to images in the "History" tab. The requests I'm after, are of course requests to images. How can I enable logging of these requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out OWASP ZAP has a global switch which controls processing of image requests, *and it is **disabled** by default*. Also, I couldn't find anything in the documentation pointing to this fact. The option in question can be found here - go to:

Tools > Options > Display > Process images in HTTP requests/responses

[image: OWASP ZAP configuration window]

**Update:** Should you be wondering why, in the History view, the IDs of requests are (still) not continuous - this is due to ZAP creating invisible "internal requests", see [here](https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/why-are-there-missing-history-ids/) for more details.